# How to create a gallery page that can be used for multiple projects?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, gallery

I will try to keep this short.

**What am I making?**
I want to create galleries for multiple projects. A gallery is opened as a new page by clicking on a project's thumbnail on the main page. Each gallery should have the same layout, just a different title, text and images.

**How do I want to make it?**
I could make multiple pages for each gallery, but I ideally want a single page of which the content is adjusted to the corresponding project. This should make it easy to adjust the layout for every gallery and add more galleries in the future. 
I was thinking of something like this:

*index.html*

```
$project1Title = "Project 1";
$project2Title = "Project 2";

<a href="gallery.html">Project1Thumbnail</a> 
(Clicking this should: gallery.html>$projectTitle=$project1Title, etc.)
<a href="gallery.html">Project2Thumbnail</a>
(Clicking this should: gallery.html>$projectTitle=$project2Title, etc.)
```

*gallery.html*

```
<h1>$projectTitle</h1>
<h2>$projectText</h2>
<ul>$projectImages</ul>
```

I know I didn't use correct syntaxes, it is just a simple example.

**What did I try?**
I tried to use php and javascript to pass variables from the main page to the gallery page, but my knowledge with these languages is not very sufficient.

**So...**
What are your suggestions on how to go about this? Creating multiple pages that take the layout from a single css file, creating a single page that takes the content from variables, or something else?

I hope everything is clear, please let me know if it is not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a limitless number of solutions to this, but a few easier ones would involve implementing some sort of basic framework to handle this for you. You're looking to build what sounds like an extremely basic content management system, you may as well just use a pre-built one.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to maximize the use of your database by storing gallery details and retrieving it using sql queries and eventually displaying it on your dynamic page (gallery). Generally database can store different kinds of data with different kinds of format such as file path.

instead of passing *"$project1Title = "Project 1";"* title use a proper variable that can be used by your database such as id.